# Instantiating YouTube_It gem Client given numerous tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api, omniauth

I've been searching for a while now, but can't seem to clarify how to successfully authenticate the YouTube_It client, so that a user can upload a video to youtube through my site.  I have omniauth-youtube working with devise, and from that I have the following:

- a `uid` (`request.env['omniauth.auth']['uid']['$t']`)
- a token (`request.env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['token']`)
- and a secret (`request.env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['secret']`)

Everything seems to be working there: users can login through YouTube.  From registering my app with Google, I also have:

- Compute/App Engine Client Id
- Compute/App Engine Email Address
- Client ID for web application
- Email address for web application
- Client secret
- Redirect URI
- Javascript Origins

YouTube_It asks for `username`, `password`, and `dev_key`.  I'm getting tripped up by the different names for everything, and the fact that YouTube_It says the longer web application ID won't work, but the shorter Computer/App Engine ID may work?  Any help clarifying how I can instantiate a new YouTubeIt::Client would be VERY appreciated.

Comment: Developer key does not seem to be accessible in the google developer console.

Comment: Ahh I may be because google has moved to the v3 api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ruby
client = YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client.new(client_access_token: TOKEN,
                                 client_refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
                                 client_id: YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,
                                 client_secret: YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                 dev_key: YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY)


#client.refresh_access_token! it might needed
video_uploaded = client.video_upload(file,
                                     title: video.title,
                                     description: video.description,
                                     category: video.category,
                                     keywords: video.tags)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I should've been more clear.  What does TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN, etc... correspond to from the tokens I have?  I am just confused because I have so many different tokens, but I appreciate the example nonetheless!

Comment: TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN are the tokens Youtube assigns to the user who grants permissions to access to his youtube account, you should save them. Token might expire, so can use REFRESH_TOKEN to get a new one.

Comment: So that would be `request.env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['token']` and `request.env['omniauth.auth']['credentials']['secret']` ?

Comment: @vh5 What's the Dev Key, in OAuth2 and V3, I'm not seeing anything referring to a dev key.

Comment: @RedRory YoutubeIT uses api v2, for v3 you should use 'google-api-client' gem  http://pastebin.com/XyA9y8y7